# Wifi driver for Windows 7 on Lenovo B460e

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers

Which wifi driver should I use in Windows 7 for a Lenovo B460e?

Comment: There are only 2 available. Install both.

Answer (score 1):

[Driver download at Lenovo's home page](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?DocID=HT072902) (first Google hit for "Lenovo B460e").

Under the heading "Networking: Wireless LAN" there are two drivers for Windows 7. They seem to be the same though (same version number, same size, just a slightly different name), so just download and install anyone of those.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [ThinkVantage System Update tool](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=TVSU-UPDATE)  This will check and present you the needed drivers and any other updates (BIOS) I find it very useful in keeping my Lenovo up to date